# How are skill nouns formed?

Tags: word-request

I was thinking, "*wielding a bow skill*" is called "**archery**", "*forging better swords, bows, armor and stuff*" is called "**smithing**", but what about "*wielding a sword*" or "*wielding a crossbow*" or "*wielding armor*"?

Are there names for other skills including these I've asked about?

P.s. I want to classify different skills into categories. Like for instance "**wielding a magic staff**" and "**mastering using scrolls**" as well as "**skills in stealing**" and those I have mentioned earlier.

Comment: Wielding a sword is called [_swashbuckling_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swashbuckler) ;-)

Comment: @J.R. Wow, that's a word.

Comment: Douglas Fairbanks knew how to swash his buckle (allegedly).

Comment: You [wield](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/wield) a tool, an instrument, a weapon, you don't wield armour (armor) or a skill. You can wield (exert) influence and power, but not for perfecting or practising (practicing)  a skill.

Comment: @Mari-LouA So wielding armor doesn't work? Then what does? Handling armor?

Comment: -craft suffix is another.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo As far as I know it conveys creating something.

Comment: @SovereignSun: And now you know better. It can also mean the *practicing* of some art or skill and need not involve creating anything. **leech-craft**, for example, is an old name for the practice of healing.  You will never guess what **wind-craft** was.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo It meant "**create wind**"?

Comment: @SovereignSun: no, it did not.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Please reveal the secret to me.

Comment: It refers to *ars plumaria*   (not arse)

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo You are one of the few users here whose words I have google up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A general word for skill in wielding swords is **swordsmanship**. **Fencing** and **swashbuckling** (as suggested by J.R.) are both more specific: fencing is a sport that uses very fast movements with light, slim swords, and swashbuckling brings to mind pirates fighting with sabres.

I'm not aware of any English word that means "skill with a crossbow."

As Mary-Lou A says, one doesn't wield armor -- one simply wears it. But I don't know of any word that means "skill in wearing armor."

Comment: For the crossbow,  *marksmanship*, maybe?

Comment: Good suggestion. Either _marksmanship_ or _archery_ is probably fine as long as the context mentions a crossbow; otherwise the listener is likely to assume a gun for marksmanship or a bow for archery. _Crossbowmanship_ is not an English word, but I bet it would be understood.

Answer (score 0):

> How are skill nouns formed?

There is no general rule. You simply need to learn the words for different skills (like archery, swordsmanship, etc.) as individual vocabulary words.